# SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000

Tags: sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB (with MVCC support enabled) along with Hibernate. In log files I am getting some warnings:

```
[WARN i.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000
[WARN i.SqlExceptionHelper] no data
```

Is there a mean to get a description of the problem based on the *Warning code* and/or *SQLState*?

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of the warning with HSQLDB without increasing the log level for hibernate's SqlExceptionHelper?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT1**
Please try following link for [HSQLDB](http://people.apache.org/~dblevins/orgapacheopenejb-029/content/org/apache/openejb/openejb-lite/4.0.0-beta-2/openejb-lite-4.0.0-beta-2.jar.contents/org/hsqldb/resources/sql-state-messages.properties) : the only information available for  **SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000** is **"no data"**

```
# SQL CODE definitions
# no data
1100=02000 no data
```

**ORIGINAL**
Please following following link and you will be able to look the description against [SQLSTATE](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzala/rzalaint.html):

```
Table 3. Class Code 02: No Data
SQLSTATE Value   
Meaning   SQLCODE Values
02000   One of the following exceptions occurred:
The result of the SELECT INTO statement or the subselect of the INSERT statement was an empty table.
The number of rows identified in the searched UPDATE or DELETE statement was zero.
The position of the cursor referenced in the FETCH statement was after the last row of the result table.
The fetch orientation is invalid.
+100
02001   No additional result sets returned. +387
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Please find updated answer, hope it helps now.

Comment: Both DB2 and HSQLDB use the SQL Standard State codes. So they are largely compatible in this area.